# terraform plan output too long for GitHub Actions comment

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I have the following code that attempts to comment 2 different `terraform plan` environments on a GitHub pull request:

```
- name: "Run - Terraform Comment"
  uses: actions/github-script@0.9.0
  env:
      STDOUT: |
        ${{ env.terraform1 }}
       
        ${{ env.terraform2 }}
  with:
    github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    script: |
      github.issues.createComment({
        issue_number: context.issue.number,
        owner: context.repo.owner,
        repo: context.repo.repo,
        body: process.env.STDOUT
      })
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Argument list too long

What is the best practice to possibly reduce the amount of output from `terraform plan` or a way to instead of commenting the text on the GitHub PR, create a file and link to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking online, I found a few different ways to reduce the size of the output.

I would recommending chopping off the top half of the `terraform plan` by adding the below code. I did not find the refreshing state information useful in the GitHub PR comment.

```
out="$(terraform plan)"
out="$(echo "${out}" | grep -v "Refreshing state")"
```

Use the `tail` command to make sure that you don't go over the max character limit on a GitHub PR comment

`out="$(echo -n "$out" | tail -c 60000)"`

Bonus points: Hiding the terraform plan in a `details` HTML tag makes the GitHub comment easy to read.

Here's the end result:

```
- name: Plan
  id: terraformplan
  run: |
        out="$(terraform plan)"
        out="$(echo "${out}" | grep -v "Refreshing state")"
        out="$(echo -n "$out" | tail -c 60000)"
        echo "::set-output name=output::$out"

- uses: actions/github-script@v5
if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
with:
  github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  script: |
    const output = `Output \
    \-
    #### Terraform Plan 
    <details><summary>Show Plan</summary>
    \`\`\`terraform\n
    ${{ steps.terraformplan.outputs.output }}
    \n\`\`\`
    </details>
    
    *Pusher: @${{ github.actor }};
    github.rest.issues.createComment({
      issue_number: context.issue.number,
      owner: context.repo.owner,
      repo: context.repo.repo,
      body: output
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using a Terraform version lower than 0.14, you may want to consider upgrading to 0.14+ as it comes with a new [Concise Diff Format](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-14-adds-a-new-concise-diff-format-to-terraform-plans) that only shows what’s different between your plan and the remote state.

If your plans are still too long, you will probably have to add each plan in a separate comment if you want to view the plans on the PR without opening a separate file.

Worst case scenario, I guess it would be possible for you to create a file with the plans, upload it to something like S3 and then create a link within the PR, but the other two methods would be preferable.